# Should MySQL temp tables be indexed (or have a primary key)?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, indexing, temp-tables

I am creating a stored procedure in MySQL which creates numerous temp tables based on the data it processes.

After nearly completing the procedure I wondered...Do these temp tables created on-the-fly really need an Unique key, Primary key, or Index?

The way I see it the data is not permanent so it's not necessary but maybe it offers some sort of optimization?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We use indexing and keys for optimizing searching (mostly). As your data is temporary (I guess you don't have to ) but ultimately you have to see the trade-off between the operations you have to perform on that data and the indexing . Introducing a primary key doesn't require any extra processing (of course your data of that column must be disciplined).
 
I can help you more  if you can give me some more info about what you have to do with data.
Also I personally recommend you not to use MYSQL for creating temporary tables. Instead use a file locally with JSON

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not want to break out of MySQL and into server code as I am just processing data that I would then store in an appropriate table. This way I avoid extra trips and gain speed. Why not since MySQL can do the processing, though I know it is meant primarily for storage.
In my case I am taking words from sentences, analyzing the amount of times they repeat. Ranking them. Then organizing the sentences based on the word rank. Finally I would like to save a summary back into a table. The summary is what I would like to show the user and why I am trying to stay within MySQL.

Comment: Alright! What I personally recommend you to do processing without MySQL. Why ? because inserting into the table takes a lot ...
Why not use your server language instead to do such type of processing 
I think arrays will be great for that. 
But if you still wish to use MYSQL and your data is fairly large I would recommend indexing!
I hope this help...

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I appreciate it. Hehe I know I'm being hard headed.

Comment: Thanks! But, if you really think I have helped you a little please +1 the answer and if your problem is resolved mark the answer as resolved . It will give me better access to site (as you can see I even can't +1 with this reputation)